# Does rate of evaporation remain same even if opposing pressure is increased?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, evaporation

Due to a question on this site I read the Vol-1 of Feynman's Lectures on Physics after a very long time.
It's in the beginning where he talks about the behavior of water molecules in a closed vessel.

> If we then take the top of the
> vessel off and blow the moist air away, replacing it with dry air, then the number
> of **molecules leaving is just the same** as it was before, because this depends on
> the jiggling of the water, but the number coming back is greatly reduced because
> there are so many fewer water molecules above the water.

Shouldn't be the number of molecules leaving the surface also be greater as the vapor pressure exerted by the humid air on the surface is also less as the humid air is replaced by dry air.
I'm no critic of Feynman, but I'm curious whether I'm wrong.

EDIT:- As @PM 2 RING says that this is a setup of Feynman, Is it too ideal to exist in reality?

Answer (score 0):

Feynman is correct. The reduced partial pressure of water vapour in the drier air reduces the rate that vapour condenses onto the liquid, but it doesn't affect the rate that the liquid evaporates. But certainly, the *net* evaporation is faster because of the reduced condensation.

If we replace the top of the container, eventually the partial pressure of the water vapour in the air above the liquid water will approach a constant value, depending on the temperature. But it's important to realise that this is a *dynamic* equilibrium.

At the equilibrium point, evaporation doesn't stop. Instead, the rate of evaporation equals the rate of condensation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong  - Why doesn't affect the rate that the liquid evaporates,because pressure is a downward force?

Comment: Air pressure also affects evaporation. If air pressure is high on the surface of a body of water, then the water will not evaporate easily. The pressure pushing down on the water makes it difficult for water to escape into the atmosphere as vapor.-https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/process-evaporation/

Comment: So, will a drop of water evaporate in a closed vessel ?

Comment: But doesn't this contradict Feynman's setup, where there is dynamic equillibrium. If it evaporates then it should also condense

Comment: So dynamic equillibrium is only possible in fully saturated air, and hence Feynman is assuming that the air around him is fully saturated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109821/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-tim-crosby).